# How can Windows Live Messenger save to whom you appear online?

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger

I'm using using Windows Live Messenger 2011 (15.4.3502.922 build) on Windows 7 64 bits.

Most of the time, when I login at work I use "offline" mode and just set to appear online to people I want to be able to contact me.

The problem is that at every login I have to remember to set to appear online to the people I want. IIRC the beta version did remember whom I've chosen to appear online and would restore those settings.

I wonder if there is a way to make Windows Live Messenger remember to whom I wish to appear online.

Comment: For anyone that comes through here, remember that Microsoft no longer supports Messenger in detriment to Skype.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to `profile.live.com`:

- Find the individual(s) you want to hide from.
- Click Details --> Manage --> Appear offline to.